# Connect to SQL Server Compact Edition in SSIS

Tags: ado.net, ssis, sql-server-ce

Till now I've been exporting data INTO the SQL Server CE database, but now in SSIS I'm attempting to source data that was inserted in a previous step of the import.

The SSIS fails during validation with the following error

Error: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsCouldNotCreateManagedConnectionException: Could not create a managed connection manager.

I am attempting to use the ADO NET Source that connects to the Data Source using the Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5 provider (i.e. ADO.NET connection manager). I CAN preview the data in the ADO.NET Source editor, but the package validation fails due to the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Compact as a source is not supported in SSIS. You must use other tools...